# Can't access to POST variable in custom form with Django

Tags: django-templates

I'm developing a website with Django.
I create a custom form directly in my template :

**HTML template**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <form action="{% url 'generate-pdf' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label>Nom</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="{{ property.name }}" required>
                <label>Prénom</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" value="{{ property.last_name }}" required>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="{{ property.email }}" required>
                <label>Texte du loyer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rent_text">
                <label>Loyer</label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" lang="en" class="form-control" id="rent" value="{{ property.rent }}" onkeyup="add_number()" required>
                <label>Provision</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="provision" onkeyup="add_number()" value="0" required>
                <label>Total du loyer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" value="{{ property.rent }}" required>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Début de la période</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="first_date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Fin de la période</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="last_date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label>Date du paiement</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="paiement_date">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I can't access to my POST variables in my view.

Here is my **views.py** :

```
def generate_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'generate_pdf.html')
```

I just have that in my request.POST :
`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['El7wZhohU8gtlY3fweFcQav0puIQbJIx0rojBvn9fItZzXg8Np7fcTsDfujArIFi']}>`

I don't know why, but I can't access to my input form variables.
I'm pretty sure it's very simple, but I'm stucked since 2h and I'm getting crazy !!

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the following?

```
request.POST.get('yourInputName')
```

Edit : The issue was with 'name' in html input as he said so there is nothing in the request.POST dictionary, So my answer in which I am trying to access a specific key will also return None instead.

Comment: print(request.POST) shows all variables, so we can see that the only variable in request.POST is 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'.
So request.POST.get('first_name') return 'None'

Comment: Why should they? Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, it's very simple : I just forget to set name attribute in all my input tags...

Answer (score 0):

**You can use post method in from tag in html**

```
   <form method="post">
```

**Then you use this method**

```
def generate_pdf(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       print(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'generate_pdf.html')
```